# Printing None using float format python

Tags: python, format, floating, nonetype

I was wondering if it were possible to print `None` as an empty string but using float format. 
Equivalence in Matlab would be `num2str([],"%3.0f")` that will return `'   '`

thanks,

Ch.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want that `"%f" % None == ""`?  If so, it's impossible because `None` and strings are built-ins and so you simply cannot modify their behaviour. You should try to give some more context anyway. This sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Why don't you use an `if` statement? `if var is None:     var =' '`

Comment: Well I wanted to avoid the use of `if` statements for that simple purpose

Answer (score 0):

this will do:

```
i = None # or test a float 
print('This is what I want: %s' % (i is None and '  ' or str(i)))
```